# This answer is confusing $4\times 4$ eigenvalue calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

> Find the rank and the four eigenvalues of the following matrix:
>
> $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$

Answer:

> The matrix has rank 2 (ensuring two zero eigenvalues) and $(1,1,1,1)$ is an
>   eigenvector with  $\lambda=2$. With trace 4, the other eigenvalue is
>   also $\lambda=2$, and it's eigenvector is $(1,-1,1,-1)$.

This is directly taken from my book. The answer does not give a clear answer as to what the four eigenvalues are.

- Is the answer $0,0,2,2$(the four eigenvalues)?
- I see that the rank is $2$ and the trace is $4$. $n-r=2$, meaning that two of the eigenvalues are $0$. The determinant is $0$. I know that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, so the sum in this case is 4. How does one calculate the two eigenvalues?

Comment: It seems the book expects you to "observe" that the rows all sum to the same value, and that therefore $(1,1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in your book says "two zero eigenvalues ... an eigenvector with $\lambda = 2$ ... the other eigenvalue is also $\lambda = 2$".

So it says the eigenvalues are $0,0,2,2$. How is this not clear?

As for how to compute them (without computing a 4x4 characteristic polynomial), you're almost there. The rank shows that two of the eigenvalues are $0$, so you have two more to find, call them $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Now the trace is $4$, so $0+0+\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = 4$. So if you can find $\lambda_1$, you'll have $\lambda_2 = 4-\lambda_1$.

Now you observe that $(1,1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector (How would you observe that? Well, it's true for any matrix all of whose rows sum to the same number). It has eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 2$, so $\lambda_2 = 2$ also.

Comment: When you say *whose rows sum to the same number*, you mean independent rows, for example $(1,0,1,0)+(0,1,0,1)=(1,1,1,1)$?

Comment: @KarlMorrison It means "the sum of the entries of *each* row is the same" . Here, that sum is $\;2\;$ and from here that eigenvalue. Good answer. +1

Comment: @Timbuc Oh so you mean the independent row $(1,0,1,0)$ would be the following $1+0+1+0=2$. Makes sense!

Comment: @KarlMorrison Th point is that when you multiply a matrix $A$ by $(1,1,1,1)$, you get a vector whose entries are the sums of the rows of $A$ (try it!). If all these sums are the same, say they're $s$, then you get the vector $(s,s,s,s)$, and thus $(1,1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalues $s$.

Comment: @KarlMorrison Alex already addressed your doubt, but the main point is that **all** the rows' entries sums equal the same.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I apologise if I am too dumb to understand, I normally require examples to figure the relationships between things. From what yous are saying this is what I'm getting in my head at the moment: $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1+0+1+0\\ 
0+1+0+1\\ 
1+0+1+0\\ 
0+1+0+1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)=(2,2,2,2)$, two however disappear because there are only $2$ independent vectors, meaning $(2,2,0,0)$?

Comment: Independent vectors and the rank of the matrix have nothing to do with this point. You computed the multiplication of $A$ with $(1,1,1,1)$ correctly (though you should write $(1,1,1,1)$ as a column vector instead of a row vector). When you computed the product, you ended up summing each row of $A$. You got $(2,2,2,2) = 2\times (1,1,1,1)$. So $(1,1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman So $(2,2,2,2)$ is the basically the scalar(eigenvalue) times the direction(eigenvector)? Are there any particular types of matrices this is done for or not done for, and what is this type of process/technique called(so I can read more on it!)?

Comment: This is just the *definition* of an eigenvector. There is absolutely nothing fancy going on here.

Answer (score 1):

If I compute $\text{det}(M-I\lambda)$, where $M$ is the matrix, $I$ the identity matrix and $\lambda$ and eigenvalue, I get:

$$\text{det}(M-I\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1-\lambda & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1-\lambda & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=4\lambda^2-4\lambda^3+\lambda^4$$

The eigenvalues must satisfy $\text{det}(M-I\lambda)=0$. Since this factors to $(\lambda-2)^2\lambda^2$, there are two eigenvalues of 2 and two eigenvalues of zero.